# Scheme: How can I change a list made with cons to a vector?

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I change this list made with `cons` to a vector?

```
((p b p b p b p b)
 (b p b p b p b p)
 (p b p b p b p b)
 (b p b p b p b p)
 (p b p b p b p b)
 (b p b p b p b p)
 (p b p b p b p b)
 (b p b p b p b p))
```

This is my code:

```
(define b "black")
(define w "white")

(define (board)
  (letrec ((ti
            (lambda (x)
          (if (eq? x 8) '()
          (cons (lh x 0) (ti (+ 1 x))))))
       (lh
        (lambda (x y)
          (if (eq? y 8) '()
          (cons (if (odd? (+ x y)) 'b 'w) (lh x (+ 1 y)))))))
    (ti 0)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`list->vector`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html) function on the whole list and then on each sublist using `vector-map`.

Or alternatively first use `map` to apply `list->vector` to each sublist and then use `list->vector` on the whole list.

Comment: Or the other way around, `(list->vector (map list->vector rows))`, would be much more consistent. :-)

Comment: @Chris: Consistent with what? As far as I can tell neither way has significant upsides compared to the other.

Comment: Consistent in that you're using `list->vector` in both places, not `list->vector` plus `vector-map`. :-) It's a very minor thing, but just the kind of thing I'd notice.

Comment: @Chris: I'd still be using `list->vector` in both places. The only difference would be that one version uses `map` and the `map` is inside and the other version uses `vector-map` and it's outside. In both cases the argument to `map`/`vector-map` is `list->vector`. Though admittedly `map` is less to type than `vector-map`, so that's one reason to prefer that version.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're thinking of?

```
#(#(p b p b p b p b)
  #(b p b p b p b p)
  #(p b p b p b p b)
  #(b p b p b p b p)
  #(p b p b p b p b)
  #(b p b p b p b p)
  #(p b p b p b p b)
  #(b p b p b p b p))
```

Comment: yes, and i used both suggestion's, thanks both for the quick, correct and useful answer. I'm not an expert in scheme or programming, but a consistent function isn't that who have more efficiency, in this case, it should be the fasted?